# SDK: Post as page on a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with adding a post on a page as a page.
I use the following code:

```
$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
$my_url = base_url().'admin/facebook/';

if(isset($_GET["code"])) {
    $code = $_GET["code"];
} else {
    $code = '';
}
if(empty($code)) {
 $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
 $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream,offline_access&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

if($_GET['state'] == $_GET['state']) {

 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

 $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);

 $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$params['access_token'];

 $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
 echo("Hello " . $user->name);

    $pageID = '212154388861617';


    // post to wall (feed is wall post, just update to whatever you want to publish to)
    try {
        //153406078098666
        $publishStream = $this->fb_ignited->api("212154388861617/feed", 'post', array(
            'message' => "Test message",
            'access_token'    => $params['access_token']
            )
        );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        die($e);
    }
}
else {
 echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
}
```

The post is correctly being added on my page but the post is being added as my user-account and not as my page-account.
How can i post as a page?
Or isn't this possible?

Solution: I added this piece of code

```
$result = $this->fb_ignited->api("/me/accounts",  array('access_token'    => $params['access_token']));
         foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
            if($page["id"] == $pageID) {
                $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
                break;
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using user's `access_token` while you need to use page `access_token`.

This can be obtained via Graph API from `accounts` connection of [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) once user granted `manage_pages` permission to your application